# Ошибка подлключения к SQL DB через System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#

Приподключении к БД возникла следующия ошибка.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Login failed for user ''.**

На БД установлено *Windows Authentication Mode*, через SQL студию подключаюсь без проблем по *Windows Authentication*.

```
        public string GetData(string param)
        {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Authentication = Windows Authentication ;Persist Security Info=False;integrated security=False;Initial Catalog=Orchestrator;server=server.domain.com");
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                {
                    command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT Status FROM [Database].[Microsoft].[table]", param);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();



                }
                connection.Close();
                return reader;
            }
```

Comment: Проверьте строку подключения, например [тут](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

Потому что VS запущен под Вашей учетной записью, а код, который Вы привели, выполняется в процессе, запущенном под другой учетной записью, например, под AppPool.

Comment: Процесс ConsoleApp стартует из под тойже учетки что и VS